# Отсутствует проект python в Qt creator

Tags: linux, ubuntu, python-3.x, qtcreator, pyqt5

Скачал онлайн установщик Qt5 с офф. сайта, кьют встала, но я не могу создать проект на Python, я понимаю что изначально Qt - это C++ IDE, но тогда как тут ведется разработка Python - проектов?

Также у меня не встал QtDesigner (может это отдельный вопрос?)
Пару часов гугления дали понять, что у Win-юзеров с этим нет проблем. All-in-one.
Хочу использовать PyQt5 и python3.
Система: Ubuntu linux 16, x64

Комрады, прошу направить заблудшего странника на истинный путь

Comment: Какие именно трудности у вас с созданием проекта? Что значит, не встал дизайнер? Он отсутствует в системе или не запускается, дает ошибку?

Comment: Трудности такие: могу создать проект только для С++, но для python только можно создать только отдельный файл..

установил либы:

sudo apt-get install python3-qt5
sudo apt-get install pyqt5-dev-tools

Comment: А там и нет возможности создавать именно проекты на питоне.

Comment: Сейчас Вы добавили боли в мою жизнь. Я то думал так всё будет легко и просто...
Спасибо огромное! Буду писать в виме

Comment: Для python есть PyCharm, очень удобная, Qt Creator и вим рядом не стояли

Answer (score 1):

в linux все следует устанавливать из пакетов. Постигните команду apt-get. Например apt-get install qtcreator. Для поиска чего нужно можно использовать apt-cache search pyqt

Comment: Спасибо за совет! Многие склоняются к установке через инсталятор, что лучше - не могу знать.

Comment: не нужно в линуксе использовать сторонние инсталляторы, если только не понимаете точно, что Вы делаете.

Comment: apt-get это и есть инсталлятор что если :)

Comment: apt-get это пакетный менеджер.

Comment: мм не правильно выразился, вы правы - да

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас уже стоят необходимые библиотеки то необходимо настроить сам qt creator. Вот ссылка на английское зеркало stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24100602/developing-python-applications-in-qt-creator

Answer (score 1):

Qt - это кроссплатформенный графический фреймворк для разработки на С++, Qt Creator - IDE. А PyQt - это набор "привязок" к этой библиотеке для python и сделан совсем другой компанией. Разработка проектов на питоне в creator'e не предусмотрена, но в новых версиях creator'a можно создавать файлы на python и запускать их, правда без поддержки автодополнения. Для разработки можно использовать любой редактор c автодополнением, который вам нравится, типа Sublime, Atom, vim и т.д. Можно использовать полноценную IDE от Jet Brains -  PyCharm Community Edition.

А Qt Designer, по идее, должен был встать с пакетом qt5, Qt Creator ведь установился? Кстати, если он установился, можно и его использовать для рисования формочек.

Comment: PyCharm бесплатный. Community издание бесплатное, но немного ограниченное по функционалу (насколько помню работа с базами через интерфейс ide отключено и что-то по мелочи)

Comment: @gil9red , да, вы правы) сейчас внесу изменения